# Limits of a double integral,

Tags: integration

[image]

From the above image, I understood how it's solved.
However, what's confusing me is the limit of $d = 2-x$, why isn't it $2$?

Comment: because you have  $x+y=2$.

Comment: @Nizar could you elaborate please...

Comment: Since you have   the range is bounded  by $x+y=2$  , $x=0$, $y=0$. Then your domian in fact is ranging in between  $0 \leq x\leq 2$ and  $0 \leq 0\leq 2-x$. To see this I advice you to plot this domain. If still the issue persist let me know.

Comment: makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The figure illustrate the region in  the $x,y$ plane limited by the given conditions.

As you see ve have:
$$
0 \le x\le 2 \quad \land \quad 0 \le y \le 2-x
$$